# is there any place in Weblogic where we can store application related passwords instead of saving it on application files.

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

is there any place in Weblogic server where we can store application related passwords and accessing it instead of saving it in application files.

Comment: why don't you use weblogic properties file?

Comment: Can you explain in detail

Comment: WebLogic does not provide out-of-the-box any security vault where you could store sensitive data such as passwords.